# com.android.contacts.ImportVCardActivity not support in Sony Ericsson Experia mini

Tags: android, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I am trying to start Import Contact activity using below code but this code is not working for Sony Ericsson Experia mini mobile hand set which have Android 2.1  I tring both option but not working.

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
               i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts","com.android.contacts.ImportVCardActivity"));
               startActivity(i);
```

or

```
 Intent intent =new Intent();
               intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts","com.android.contacts.vcard.ImportVCardActivity"));
               startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.sonyericsson.contacts",
  "com.sonyericsson.contacts.contactlist.ImportVCardActivity"));
```